# Does memory used of returned variables from functions need to be freed (C)?

Tags: c, memory-management, return-value

Let's suppose I have the following C code:

```
void myfunction() {
    time_t     t = 0;
    struct tm  *ct;

    time(&t);
    ct = localtime(&t);
}
```

As you can see, the `localtime` function returns a new pointer to a `struct tm` variable. From what I know, for a returned variable from a function to be valid in the caller context it needs to fulfill at least one of the following:

1. The returned variable must be declared in the caller's context or a higher context related to caller.
2. The returned variable must have the allocated memory on the heap.

In my case the first point does not apply, so it is normal to think that 2nd is fulfilled.

Am I right?

If yes, does that mean that I need to call free on `ct` variable after using it?

If not, can you detail a little bit?

Thanks!

---

EDIT:

From the responses, I understood that there should be another point in the requirements that a variable to be usable in the context where returned. That should be the static variables. Is there another possibility?

Comment: It depends.  You read the documentation and then, well, you'll know.  More often than not, no.

Comment: The other possibilities are somewhat more obscure, but memory mapped files are not, strictly speaking, allocated off the heap but are still accessible.  Also, in the embedded world, there may be memory addresses that correspond to physical hardware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several older C functions return pointers to static buffers.  `localtime` is one of those.  You do not need to (and indeed should not; you will probably segfault your program if you do) free the returned pointer from `localtime`.

The problem is that there is one and only one `localtime` buffer in the process space, and the next call to `localtime` (even in another thread) will overwrite the results returned previously.  This is why nearly all functions that behave that way (`strtok` is another example) now have new `_r` versions that put their results in a buffer passed in by the user and are therefore threadsafe.

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not need to free it:

> The returned value points to an internal object whose validity or
>   value may be altered by any subsequent call to gmtime or localtime.

[Source](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/localtime/)

In other words, if you want to save the return value of this function, you should manually save it elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Verbatim from `man localtime` on Linux:

> The  four  functions  asctime(),  ctime(),  gmtime()  and localtime() return a pointer to static data and hence are not thread-safe.

So no, there is no need to free the value returned by `localtime()`, even more you shall not even try to free it.

OT: To stay thread-safe the man page states:

> Thread-safe versions asctime_r(), ctime_r(), gmtime_r() and localtime_r() are specified by
>          SUSv2, and available since libc 5.2.5.

Comment: If I call `localtime_r` instead of `localtime`, does that mean that I need to call `free` on returned value when no longer needed?

Comment: @artaxerxe With `struct tm *localtime_r(const time_t *timep, struct tm *result);` the value returned points to the buffer provided by the caller as an additional second parameter. So if `free()`ing the result is necessary depends on how the buffer passed in had been allocated.

Comment: I beg your pardon. My lack of documentation. Thanks for patience.:)